# How to refresh access token with iOS SDK

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I am using both iOS & Android SDK. I can refresh new access token when my android app comes to foreground from background via refreshAuthToken function. But I can not do that with iOS SDK. I also want to refresh access token when my iOS comes to foreground from background. Can anyone show me how to refresh access token with iOS SDK?﻿